# PHP PDO, connecting to database/selecting database + execute

Tags: php, pdo

This is my code http://prntscr.com/a2d8qq currently, I am learning things but I am really wondering why it will say that there is no database selected, tho I have selected it in line 5, also if I remove the `"dbname = users_details"` and then execute a query that creates a databse then it is fine. But whenever I create a table in that database (I selected it) it will not make me, I searched across google and it really is the same to my code but mine will not work.

```
<?php

    try {

        $connect = new PDO("mysql: host = 'localhost'; dbname = users_details", 'root', '');
        $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE MyGuests (
                        id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                        firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                        lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                        email VARCHAR(50),
                        reg_date TIMESTAMP
                        )";

                $connect->exec($sqlQuery);
                    echo 'Successfully created table.';

    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {

        echo $e->getMessage();

    }
?>
```

Comment: do you have a database named `user_details`? if you take that out, then you HAVEN'T specified a default database, and mysql has no idea WHICH of the many databases it can host you want to create your table in.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply this is currently what I have in my phpmyadmin and my code: http://prntscr.com/a2dfzh

Comment: [it's important to follow the proper format - no fancy spaces or other decorations have to be used in the DSN.](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dsn)

Comment: I'm not quite sure about this, but try adding database name along with the table name, like this: `$sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE users_details.MyGuests ( ...`

Comment: ^ Oh I think this is more efficient than what I just have posted as answer.

Answer (score -1):

So this fixed my problem: I have to execute a query to use a specified database into where I want my tables to be in. Then in the line 5 I have just removed the "dbname =

```
<?php

try {

    $connect = new PDO("mysql: host = 'localhost';", 'root', '');
    $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sqlQuery = "CREATE TABLE details (
                    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                    email VARCHAR(50),
                    reg_date TIMESTAMP
                    )";

            $connect->exec("use users_details");
            $connect->exec($sqlQuery);
                echo 'Successfully created table.';

}

catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}
```

?>

Comment: Rajdeeps Paul comment nails it for efficiency I guess, I have OC problems so, I think hes idea is good.